# Histogram of large matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, histogram

I have a large, square sparse matrix in R (about 30M real numbers), and I'd like to see the distribution of its values.
If I use the **hist** function, as most values are 0, I get a very tall first bar and then a very long tail very close to 0, something like: I_***_*____**

So I guess I should print only nonzero values, or rescale the values in order to show the pattern of non zero values in a meaninful way.
Is there a way to tell hist to filter out certain values?
I'd like to include only values in (0,1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A matrix is just a vector that's been told about it's column and row assignments... it'll turn back into one if you just treat it like one.  .....

```
hist( myMatrix[myMatrix > 0 & myMatrix < 1] )
```